# How to randomise the order of items in a tasks environment?

Tags: exsheets, tasks, random

I have set up a document with a structure like this

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{tasks}

\newcommand{\righty}{$\checkmark$}
\newcommand{\checky}{$\Box$}

\SetupExSheets{counter-format=se.qu,counter-within=section}
\settasks{label={\checky}}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
    How much do you like your teacher?
    \begin{tasks}
        \task[\righty] I'm indifferent to this
        \task I hate them to death
        ...
    \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, this document is generating the solutions to the questions at the moment. I would now like to add a switch to generate the unanswered questions as well, randomizing the items in the task environments.

Is something like this possible without changing the current structure? I have right about 250 questions inside that document, so it would be in my best interest not to change each of these, but best practice is always appreciated. I'm sorry for that kind of request, but I'm far too new to such tasks that I would knew where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the switch is as easy as this:

```
\newif\ifanswers
% \answerstrue % uncomment to display answers

\newcommand{\righty}{\ifanswers$\checkmark$\else\checky\fi}
```

With this you only need to comment or uncomment `\answerstrue` for the two versions of the document.

Shuffling the items of the `tasks` environment is not that hard either albeit a hack because it requires a redefinition of a `tasks` internal. *Be aware that the order will be shuffled differently each time you re-compile*:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \tasks_environment:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l__tasks_debug_bool { \dim_set:Nn \fboxsep {0pt} }
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tasks_seq {#3} {#4}
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tasks_seq \l__tasks_tmpa_tl
    \seq_shuffle:N \l__tasks_seq % <<< this is added
    \tl_if_blank:VF \l__tasks_tmpa_tl
      { \msg_warning:nnVn {tasks}{no-item} \l__tasks_tmpa_tl {#3} }
    \int_gset:Nn \g__tasks_total_items_int
      { \seq_count:N \l__tasks_seq }
    \UseInstance {tasks} {#1}
      { \g__tasks_total_items_int }
      {#2}
      { }
    \seq_clear:N \l__tasks_seq
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

---

The complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{tasks}

\newif\ifanswers
% \answerstrue % uncomment to display answers

\newcommand{\righty}{\ifanswers$\checkmark$\else\checky\fi}
\newcommand{\checky}{$\Box$}

\SetupExSheets{counter-format=se.qu,counter-within=section}
\settasks{label={\checky}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \tasks_environment:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l__tasks_debug_bool { \dim_set:Nn \fboxsep {0pt} }
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tasks_seq {#3} {#4}
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tasks_seq \l__tasks_tmpa_tl
    \seq_shuffle:N \l__tasks_seq % <<< this is added
    \tl_if_blank:VF \l__tasks_tmpa_tl
      { \msg_warning:nnVn {tasks}{no-item} \l__tasks_tmpa_tl {#3} }
    \int_gset:Nn \g__tasks_total_items_int
      { \seq_count:N \l__tasks_seq }
    \UseInstance {tasks} {#1}
      { \g__tasks_total_items_int }
      {#2}
      { }
    \seq_clear:N \l__tasks_seq
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  How much do you like your teacher?
  \begin{tasks}
  \task[\righty] I'm indifferent to this
  \task I hate them to death
  \task What is Love?
  \task I have a crush.
  \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nothing to add, just that I like your sense of humour